# How do I 'pre-filter' data in my Laravel model?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, graphql

I'm using Laravel + Lighthouse PHP (GraphQL) to grab a list of dates (`instances`) associated with a training course:

Schema:

```
type Query{
    course(slug: String! @eq): Course @find
}

type Course{
    id: ID!
    title: String!
    instances(
          "Order by date"
          orderBy: [OrderByClause!] @orderBy
        ): [Instance!] @hasMany
}
```

Request:

```
/graphql?query=query+{course(slug:"${this.$route.params.slug}"){
                title,
                instances(orderBy:[{field:"start_date",order: ASC}]){
                    id,
                    start_date,
                    end_date,
                    price,
                }
            }
```

This works fine, but it returns *all* the dates for any given course. What I would like is to filter out past dates, which are obviously useless. As I'm using graphQL I don't have a controller, so I assume I need to add some kind of getter function in my Model to filter out past dates, and then access that function via graphQL (maybe Lighthouse's `@method` directive?) but I have no idea how to do that. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Worked it out, it was almost too simple in the end.

In my `Course` model I simply added an Eloquent `where` to my `instances` return:

```
public function instances(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Instance::class)->where('start_date','>',Carbon::now()->format('Ymd'));;
    }
```

using Carbon to grab the current date to compare to.